# Load Balancer PHP FPM AND HHVM Apache 2.4

Tags: php, proxy, hhvm, apache2.4

Hi I try to do a load balancer in Apache 2.4. I am using PHP-FPM and HHVM.

I NEED in case HHVM fail will transfer the traffic to PHP-FPM  For do that I configure Php-Fpm in port 9005 and HVM in port 9000.

I try many configurations but in case I stop HVM the traffic is not redirect to php-fpm I got always a ERROR PAGE.

Here is last configuration I try but that not works us expected.

First I setup HHVM in Port 9000
Second PHP FPM in Port 9005

And here is my config in VHOST

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/mydomain.com/$1
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9005/var/www/mydomain.com/$1
<Proxy balancer://127.0.0.1/>
    BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:9000 route=thin0
    BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:9005 route=thin1
</Proxy>
```

Comment: Please edit your post and use punctuation so that it's better understandable.

Comment: I done that better now?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this exact setup and spent many hours on trying to figure out something that will work. You have almost got it right here... but I ended up ditching the ProxyPassMatch stuff, and going with "all PHP" files get handled by the load balancer, and then the loadbalancer simply routes to one of the 2 engines.

```
<Proxy "balancer://mycluster">
    BalancerMember fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000 loadfactor=99
    BalancerMember fcgi://127.0.0.1:9100 loadfactor=1
</Proxy>

<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:balancer://mycluster"
</FilesMatch>
```

The loadfactor stuff wasnt required, but I did want to make HHVM handle "most" of my requests.